# Expected identifier or string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, visual-studio-2010, response

```
function GetHTML(url, para) {
   var data =  $.ajax({
        url: url,
        global: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: para,
        dataType: "html",
        async: false,
    }).responseText;
    return data;
}
```

well when i run this function it's work good but i got the problem that Visual studio tell me `Expected identifier or string`

are their anything goes wrong in this code. well tell me what i do to remove this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the comma after `async: false`,

Try using [jslint](http://www.jslint.org) - it can help pick up things like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the extra comma after `async: false,` - that is a syntax error, and wouldn't work on all browsers (If I remember correctly, it doesn't work on IE)