# Strange IE7 quirk

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the following error in `IE9` when in `IE7` mode. Using a small counting script:

> SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

***Code***

```
$.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
    to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
    speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
    refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
    decimals: 2,  // the number of decimal places to show
    onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
    onComplete: null,  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
};
```

**Line 185** is the last curly bracket and semi colon

We need this to work in `IE7` but this error is breaking the script.

Comment: I really suggest not using Browser Compatibility mode to test IEs. These modes are almost, but not quite, exactly unlike their real counter parts. Here's a link to Microsofts Virtual PCs for testing the multiple IE versions: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575

Comment: +1 to @JaredMcAteer's comment. Plus of the three words in the post title two are redundant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expected identifier or string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930960/expected-identifier-or-string-in-javascript) This was the top result when typing the error message into the search box. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Expected+identifier%2C+string+or+number

Comment: thanks for the heads up on MS virtual PC's

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the trailing comma after `onComplete`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$.fn.countTo.defaults = {
   from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
   to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
   speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
   refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
   decimals: 2,  // the number of decimal places to show
   onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
   onComplete: null  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
};
```

Remove the comma after `onComplete: null`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the last comma on the final value of your defaults. IE has an issue with this. make it like this and you should be good:

```
$.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
    to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
    speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
    refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
    decimals: 2,  // the number of decimal places to show
    onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
    onComplete: null  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
};
```